# Suspend isn't working anymore after upgrade to xubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, xfce, suspend, xubuntu

Suspend doesn't halt my old computer (DELL Precision T7400) since I updated to xubuntu 15.10.

I have a black screen after suspending but the computer is still working (fan, led, ...)

I suspect systemd to mess up with pm-suspend.

I tried to suspend in different ways:

```
pm-suspend

xfce4-session-logout --suspend

Uswsusp (s2ram)

dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend`
```

I have all the times the same result: blank screen but still power.

Any fixing ideas?

Comment: Same behavior on my side with xubuntu 15.10. As a workaround, I do the following: * crtl-alt-f1 to switch to text console
* login in text console
* 'ps aux | grep lightdm' to find the process number of lightdm
* 'sudo kill -9 [process number of lightdm]' to restart lightdm, the old fashion way As lightdm restarts, the sytem switch again to lightdm login. Any findings on your side ?

Comment: @peb The problem was linked to my graphical driver (Nvidia). I removed the proprietary driver and installed the free one (xserver-xorg-video-nouveau) and suspend works now.